# Get Weight from Weighing Machine which is connected to COM1 and Get Fat content in milk from optional VGA

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have tried to develop an application to read Weight from Weighing Machine. I have used WPF and MVVM to complete this task.

Here is my code:

*MainWindow.xaml*

```
<Window .............>
    <Window.DataContext>
        <vm:MainWindowViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="10" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="10" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="10" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" FontSize="24" Text="Weight :" />
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" FontSize="24" Text="{Binding Weight}" />
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" FontSize="24" Text="Fat :" />
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" FontSize="24" Text="{Binding Fat}" />
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" FontSize="24" Text="Ports :" />
        <ComboBox Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" FontSize="24" ItemsSource="{Binding SerialPorts}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

*MainWindowViewModel.cs*

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    SerialPort spCom1;
    SerialPort spCom2;

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        spCom1 = new SerialPort("COM1", 9600, Parity.None, 8);
        spCom1.ReadTimeout = 1000;
        spCom1.DataReceived += spCom1_DataReceived;

        spCom2 = new SerialPort("COM2", 9600, Parity.None, 8);
        //115200 -- baudrate
        spCom2.ReadTimeout = 1000; 
        spCom2.DataReceived += spCom2_DataReceived;

        SerialPorts = new ObservableCollection<string>(SerialPort.GetPortNames());
    }

    void spCom1_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        spCom1.Open();
        Weight = spCom1.ReadExisting().ToString();
        spCom1.Close();
    }

    void spCom2_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        spCom2.Open();
        Fat = spCom2.ReadExisting().ToString();
        spCom2.Close();
    }

    private string _weight;
    public string Weight
    {
        get
        {
            return _weight;
        }
        set
        {
            _weight = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Weight");
        }
    }

    private string _fat;
    public string Fat
    {
        get
        {
            return _fat;
        }
        set
        {
            _fat = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Fat");
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<string> _serialPorts;
    public ObservableCollection<string> SerialPorts
    {
        get
        {
            return _serialPorts;
        }
        set
        {
            _serialPorts = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("SerialPorts");
        }
    }

}
```

As you can see from the above mentioned code, I am trying to get Weight from a Weighing Machine which is connected to COM1. As well as I am trying to get Amount of Fat Content of Milk from its Machine which outputs data from RS232 port and CPU recieves signals from an optional VGA port. But When I connect a Weighing Machine I does not get any data at all. So, is there any problem with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void spCom1_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    spCom1.Open();
    ....
```

You will have to Open the Com port *before* any DataReceived event can happen.

You are configuring the ports but you never Open them. Start with a simple Button.

Comment: I open them in dataReceived event

Comment: ..and DataReceived event can only happen after the Com port opened @Vishal

Comment: @har07 so, where should i open the connection?

Comment: ... Start with a simple Button. Please read the answers you get.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I now understood the meaning of your answer. I have tried to open and close the ports with the help of buttons. Is there any other change that is to be made? And the DataReceived event Handler is declared in the constructor of MainWindowViewModel as shown in the code in question. Should I change that as well? I am asking this because just now I am not in front of Weighing machine. So I need to complete the code before testing it on a machine.

Comment: 1) verify the creation and opening of the ports with the debugger. 2) ReadExisiting may not return all data. Google for how to use COM ports.